# How to Encrypt both ASMX Web Service request and response without using HTTPS & SSL

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, encryption

i have come across a msdn article `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972410.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396` which guide how to design a web service which send response in encrypted form without using HTTPS & SSL. we just need to add one attribute for return response in encrypted form. a sample code as follows

```
public class CreditCardService {

  [WebMethod]
  [EncryptionExtension(Encrypt=EncryptMode.Response)]
  public string GetCreditCardNumber() {
    return "MC: 4111-1111-1111-1111";
  }
}
```

1) i like to know what dll i need to include as a result as a result i could use this attribute **[EncryptionExtension(Encrypt=EncryptMode.Response)]** for web method ?

2) can i encrypt request and response both using this attribute **EncryptionExtension** ? i am not before dev environment so could not test it. so please some one share knowledge.

3) my main concern is to encrypt my web service request and response without using SSL & HTTPS and also i do not like to write any routine which encrypt request and response xml of web service. i want some automated way which encrypt my web service request and response automatically. guide me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you read the whole article, you'll see that you need to implement your own SOAP Extension that will provide the necessary encryption. The SOAP extension should look like this:

```
public class EncryptionExtension : SoapExtension { 

  public override void ProcessMessage(SoapMessage message) {
    switch (message.Stage) {

      case SoapMessageStage.BeforeSerialize:
       break;

      case SoapMessageStage.AfterSerialize:
        Encrypt();
        break;

      case SoapMessageStage.BeforeDeserialize:
        Decrypt();
        break;

      case SoapMessageStage.AfterDeserialize:
        break;

      default:
        throw new Exception("invalid stage");
      }
   }
...
}
```

The rest of the article describes how to implement the encryption algorithm and so on. It should be fairly easy to follow along

Comment: with the help of soap extension can we encrypt request and response both? when client send data from his side to service end then request will be encrypted ? please guide. thanks

Comment: if possible guide me with full small code like how to implement it for any ASMX web service. thanks

Comment: You can encrypt the response. The request will need to be encrypted by the client using the same symmetric or asymmetric keys. I'm afraid SO works on a different model. We can help you with your code, but you have to make the effort to write something in the first place

Comment: thanks for reply. u said `The request will need to be encrypted by the client using the same symmetric or asymmetric keys` r u trying to say client need to write code to encrypt request. suppose i developed a web service and few other client may use that....so it would be their responsibility to encrypt data before send to my service end and for that they need to write code for encryption?

Comment: That's correct. What use will it be to the client if you respond with encrypted data they cannot decrypt? If the client is only going to consume, then they need to be able to decrypt that data. If they need to send sensitive data as well, then they also need to be able to encrypt it. That's why SSL was invented, to solve this problem in the first place, so what you're trying to do is re-invent the wheel